# Class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged null PropertyChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

I see this question asked alot on here, but it's always WPF, and I am using WinForms.

I have a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and when OnPropertyChanged is called in one of the properties setters, the PropertyChanged event object is always null, so the event is never raised.

```
public abstract class ProxyScraperSiteBase : IProxyScraperSite, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private int scrapedCount;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler<PageScrapedEventArgs> PageScraped;

    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public List<Proxy> ScrapedProxies { get; set; } = new List<Proxy>();
    public int ScrapedCount {
        get
        {
            return this.scrapedCount;
        }
        set
        {
            this.scrapedCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public abstract Task ScrapeAsync(IWebDriver driver, PauseOrCancelToken pct = null);

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected void OnPageScraped(List<Proxy> proxies)
    {
        if (PageScraped != null)
        {
            PageScraped(this, new PageScrapedEventArgs(proxies));
        }
    }
}
```

***Setting bindings***

```
public partial class ProxyScraperForm : Form
{

    private BindingList<IProxyScraperSite> sites = new BindingList<IProxyScraperSite>();

    public ProxyScraperForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sites.Add(new ProxyScraperSiteUsProxyOrg());

        ScraperDataGridView.DataSource = sites;
    }

    private void ScrapeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var site in sites)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {

                site.PageScraped += Site_PageScraped;
                var driver = SeleniumUtility.CreateDefaultFirefoxDriver();
                await site.ScrapeAsync(driver);
                driver.Quit();
            });
        }
    }

    private void Site_PageScraped(object sender, PageScrapedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScraperDataGridView.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            ((IProxyScraperSite)sender).ScrapedCount += e.Proxies.Count;
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are in WinForms what makes you think anything is subscribing to PropertyChanged?

Comment: While INotifyPropertyChanged is primarily used in WPF/UWP and the MVVM pattern, it is a very old Interface dating back to 2.0. The only difference is that you usually have to manually register the Event, as you do not have all those WPF/UWP/MVVM related classes like bindings to take that problem off you.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Databinding must suscribe to `PropertyChanged` if the source object implements `INotifyPropertyChange`, just exactly the same as in WPF.

Comment: @Alejandro Yeah, that's exactly what I am trying to do.  I'm not sure how else to have a BindingList automatically update the DGV it is bound to other than implementing INotifyPropertyChanged here.  From what I have read on here and Google, it is the way to achieve this functionality, even in WinForm apps.

Comment: @DavidStampher What you're doing here is totally correct. The problem must be elsewhere, like not setting the bindings correctly or failing to set this object as the data source. Otherwise you would see some handler in the event.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for the response.  I updated my question to show the code where I am binding to a DataGridView.

Comment: Your interface should be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, not the derived class. Since you only bind on `BindingList<IProxyScraperSite>`, it doesn't know anything about `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the concrete class.

Comment: @RonBeyer If you want to post that as an answer I can mark it.  That solved my problem.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to `IProxyScraperSite`, but that interface does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The binding only knows about the interface, not the concrete class, so it has no idea that `INotifyPropertyChanged` has been implemented. The fix is simple, move the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the `IProxyScraperSite` interface:

```
public interface IProxyScraperSite : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
}
```

This will allow your `BindingList` to subscribe to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event since it can now see that the binding object implements it.